# Issue when calling the .exe file through batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, exe

I have a problem when calling the .exe file through a batch script. Below is my batch script code:

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=* delims=" %%A in (MyFile.csv) do start " "diffapicmdline.exe /lhscd "/d=localhost:9080 /h=localhost /u=user1 /p=Pwd123 %%A" /rhscd "/d=localhost:9080 /h=localhost /u=user1 /p=Pwd123 Prjct %%A" /t job /ot html /ol "C:\compare_output_H_S_Component.html""
```

So for each row in `MyFile.csv` file `diffapicmdline.exe` should be called every time.

But the problem is that it is not recognizing the parameters after .exe. Do we have to escape characters or find other ways to tell the batch script to run .exe successfully?

Error I am receiving here:

```
Windows can't find 'diffapicmdline.exe /lhscd "/d=localhost:9080'. 
Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again.
```

Comment: `do start " ""diffapicmdline.exe`: what's this funny quote pattern ? Is that on purpose ?

Comment: Could you edit question and paste the error message you have ?

Comment: @kebs diffapicmdline.exe is a utility provided by IBM to compare the DataStage jobs across different hosts. Its on purpose only and its expected format. When I execute the same individually in cmd its working perfectly. But I want to utilize the same in batch script to automate the comparing of jobs.

Comment: That was not what I asked, and is not relevant in the question. My question is why three: `"""` ?

Comment: Do you have spaces in  the fields of you csv file ? That could cause an issue.

Comment: Did you make sure the .exe file is accessible from the path ?

Comment: Thanks for pointing quotes @kebs. I edited it and its working now.

Comment: one more question is I would like to process next value in the variable when this command is executed successfully. How can I do that?

Comment: Use `start "" "[\path\to\]executable.exe" [arguments of executable]`; you have many quotes `"` within the `start` command line which are not correct; the first `""` here constitutes an empty string that tells `start` to use it as the window title; if you omit it, `start` may try to take the executable path/name as the title and its first argument as the executable to run, which will for sure fail...

Answer (score 0):

Would this work better, calling the exe in-line instead of launching a new CMD process?

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=* delims=" %%A in (MyFile.csv) do diffapicmdline.exe /lhscd "/d=localhost:9080 /h=localhost /u=user1 /p=Pwd123 %%A" /rhscd "/d=localhost:9080 /h=localhost /u=user1 /p=Pwd123 Prjct %%A" /t job /ot html /ol "C:\compare_output_H_S_Component.html"
```